# Storing messages in ejabberd

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to setup simple XMPP server (ejabberd) which will save messages exchanged by users in MySql database.

This really seems like a basic stuff for a chat server.

Does anyone have any experience or documentation on how to setup message storing?

I am using ejabberd 15.04

Comment: For iOS xmpp bydefault manage and store your messages in core database. No need to create database for chat.

Comment: I have the same problem with the database
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808877/ejabberd-16-06-mysql-5-5-50-message-history-is-not-saved
Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [ejabberd forums](https://www.ejabberd.im/node/24959), ejabberd since version 15.06 supports Message Archive Management (MAM) with both Mnesia and relational database storage (MySQL, Postgres).

You can upgrade to ejabberd 15.06 to benefit from that feature.

Comment: I have successfully implemented one on one chat in my iOS application. I have used CoreData to save the chat between two users as in app database. But this chat is removed when the user uninstalls the application. What i need to know is how i can save the chat between two users on my server so whenever the user reinstalls the app or logs in any other device he can see his previous chat. I have enable mod_archive and mod_mam on my ejabberd server and i am able to retrieve offline messages in the app. Thanks

Comment: You need to enable MAM on ejabberd and support MAM protocol in your client.

Comment: MAM is enabled on ejabberd and iam unable to fetch the chat history between two users. Will you please help me in implementing XMPPMessageArchiveManagement.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Hi..!! 

I am facing the same issue in my android app also. I am able to receive the offline messages. But i don't know i can retrieve the chat history of one to one chat in my app. I searched on google a lot about this and found that i need to use MamManager but i am unable to resolve it in my Android Studio.

Comment: You actually need to implement this XMPP specification in your client / library: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Do we have a .jar file or any library for that? Below are the dependencies which i have added. 

    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-minidns:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-sasl-provided:4.1.6'
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.6"

Comment: It seems MAM is implemented in latest version of Smack: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/pull/76 Please refer to your library documentation :)