# ejabberd 16.06 + mysql 5.5.50, message history is not saved

Tags: mysql, message, archive, ejabberd, history

I use ejabberd 16.06 + mysql 5.5.50, message history is not saved.

My ejabberd.yml:

```
## MySQL server:

odbc_type: mysql 
odbc_server: "freldo"
odbc_port: 3306
odbc_database: "ejabberd"
odbc_username: "ejabberd" 
odbc_password: "ejabberd"

modules: 
... 
mod_mam: 
   db_type: odbc 
   default: always
```

for the formation of the database structure, I used: 
[mysql.sql](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/83cce468a573d3ca58a0c6653a2ccc17c7b4dbc3/sql/mysql.sql)

I get an error:

> @ejabberd_sql:check_error:1039 SQL query 'SELECT timestamp, xml, peer,
>   kind, nick FROM (SELECT timestamp, xml, peer, kind, nick FROM archive
>   WHERE username='test' and bare_peer='misha@freldo' ORDER BY timestamp
>   DESC limit 21) AS t ORDER BY timestamp ASC;' failed: "#42S22Unknown
>   column 'kind' in 'field list'"

I have not saved message history in database.

Comment: kind column name does not exist in archive table.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your mysql to version 5.6+ should solve your problem.

> ejabberd make use of FULLTEXT indexes with InnoDB. Thus, you need
>   MySQL 5.6 or greater to use with ejabberd.
>
> Note: If you do not store message archive in database however, you can
>   try using older 5.5 version. You may need to adapt MySQL database
>   schema to cope with those older MySQL versions.

MySQL version 5.6.4 or higher is [recommended](https://github.com/processone/docs.ejabberd.im/blob/master/content/admin/guide/databases/mysql.md#requirements) if you want to store message history.

Comment: openfire moved on and forgotten for these problems. thanks for the help.